# With the audio tool sox, how can I determine whether a stereo recording is in fact mono?

Tags: audio, channel, sox, phase

I have stereo files (2-channel-WAV) which sound totally like mono recordings. Is there a way to let [`sox`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) run over the file and output whewther the 2 channels are the same or not?

Or is there another command line tool doing this sort of wave comparison aggregating the differences between the to channels of a sound file into a "similarity number"?

Answer (score 4):

You can invert one channel and add it to the other one (thereby subtracting them), then check if the difference is zero:

```
$ sox input.wav -n remix 1,2i stats
DC offset   0.000000
Min level   0.000000
Max level   0.000000
Pk lev dB       -inf
RMS lev dB      -inf
...
```

If `Pk lev dB` shows as `-inf`, channels 1 and 2 are identical.

This may or may not give meaningful results for channels that are very similar but not identical. A simple phase shift, e.g., might lead to a large difference sample-wise, but still sound exactly the same.